# Random array special

Tags: php, optimization, arrays, random

how make special random array. i have `array(1=>35,2=>25,3=>40)`. how make possibility that array show special elements. Ex.
If i want get 100 elements from array. it will be

```
35/100 +-10 - must bee 1 element,
25/100 +-10 = must be 2 element,
40/100 +-10 - must be 3 element.
```

Elements must be random, but most elements +-10. i know its possible make by this code:

```
$a = array_fill(1, 35, 1);
$b = array_fill(36, 60, 2);
$c = array_fill(61, 100, 3);
```

array looks like `array(35 elements with value 1, 25 elements with value 2, 40 elements with value 3)`
and using merge and array_rand i will get my code. But i don't want this code. it will be create 100 items. need optimization this code. it's possible. help. :-)

Comment: You want to create an array with 100 elements so that the number of elements with value 1 is `a in [25,45]`, the number of elements with value 2 is `b in [15,35]` and the number of values with value 3 is `c in [30,50]`? Your problem is subspecified, you need to tell what distributions `a`, `b` and `c` follow. Without it, we cannot tell e.g. if it is as likely you get `a=25` as `c=50`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for a weighted random array?

Check this example:

http://20bits.com/articles/random-weighted-elements-in-php/

Comment: @Valdas This is not the same you asked... You definitely did not ask for a categorical distribution because of your two constraints – that the variation is only +- 10 and that the sum of all is 100.